# How to return a particular data class from a list of sealed classes

Tags: kotlin

I would like know how I can return a data class from a list of sealed classes.
For example, I have :

```
data class Payroll(
   val items: List<Inventory> 
)
```

```
sealed class Inventory {
  data class testOne(val amount: Int)
  data class testTwo(val isProd: Boolean)
}
```

I would like to return testTwo class so I can perform a check on `isProd`.

I tried:

```
payroll.items.find{ it is Inventory.testTwo}
```

it returns `TestTwo` but as an `Inventory` so I cannot access testTwo.isProd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `testOne` and `testTwo` in your example do not subtype `Inventory`. I assume this is just a mistake when preparing the example for StackOverflow.

If you need to find the first `testTwo` item or null if there is none, you can do it like this:

```kotlin
payroll.items.firstNotNullOfOrNull { it as? Inventory.testTwo }
```

Or if you need to find all `testTwo` items:

```kotlin
payroll.items.filterIsInstance<Inventory.testTwo>()
```